# Make element fixed position, but follow page scroll if content too big

Tags: html, css, position

See [this webpage](http://majorresume.lostbeans.com/).

1. First try scroll it, see that the left bar remains fixed.
2. Resize the height of your window, so that not all of the content of the left bar is visible. Now scroll. This time, the left bar is not fixed.

In this page, there is a jquery that calculates height of left bar, compares it to the window-height and then makes the left bar position fixed or absolute.

However, I'm wondering if something similar is achievable through just HTML and CSS, not using jQuery or similar.

Any suggestions?
In short what I'm looking for is a bar with content that remains fixed, but is scrolled if the content overflows. But the scrolling should be together with the whole page.

Comment: This sounds like absolute and relative positioning, not fixed.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Why do you say that? Having the bar position:fixed; is what I want, except that if the content is too big I can't see it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on media queries but take a look at this - direct CSS to certain screen sizes, so you could use one stylesheet if the screen is too small. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: If you're following a page scroll, it's not fixed; fixed is in reference to the screen, not the content.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs did you even take a look at the webpage? It IS fixed as long as the content does not exceed the heigth of the column, else it is scrollable.

Comment: @Raeki Damn, that works like a charm. It's not as dynamic as the jQuery, as I will have to set a treshold-size manually. But in my case that's ok. Please post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Christoph, did you even read my comment?  This SOUNDS like absolute and relative positioning.  Fixed positioning doesn't "follow" anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use media queries to direct CSS at certain screen sizes (and other things too) so you could use one stylesheet if the screen is too small. I'm no expert so no examples, but take a look here http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ . Sorry! but guess you figured it out :)

Edit: The working result is this:

```css
#leftnav {
    /* default look */
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
}

/* set the size at which the content is clipped and we cannot have fixed position */
@media all and (max-height: 500px) {
    /* things inside here will only have an effect if the browser window shows
       less than 500 px in the height, so here I apply the special rules */
    #leftnav {
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        /* etc.. */
    }
}
```